# Summernote pastHTML add unwanted extra lines.

Tags: summernote

I am loading user input back into summernote for editing, both top and bottom get extra lines added on. Is there a way to fix it?

```
$('#summernote').summernote('editor.pasteHTML', "<p>hello world</p>");
```

comes out

"

hello world

"

instead of  "hello world"

Comment: stuck in same issue. :(

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem. If you're trying to initialize the editor with html, try doing `$('#summernote').summernote('code', "<p>hello world</p>");` instead. The `$('#summernote').summernote('code', markupString);` is for setting the html directly.